Getting ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++_shared in my react native project (android)
So whenever i am trying to build my android project it is giving me this issue:
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=x86_64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=C:/Users/ishan/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libreact_codegen_rnscreens.so -o C:\Projects\Mingle-Now-Frontend\android\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\526c1e5g\obj\x86_64\libreact_codegen_rnscreens.so rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/6f07d97784e7e6cda5573e648feede57/common/cpp/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/RNSModalScreenShadowNode.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/6f07d97784e7e6cda5573e648feede57/common/cpp/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/RNSScreenShadowNode.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/6f07d97784e7e6cda5573e648feede57/common/cpp/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/RNSScreenState.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/rnscreens.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/35cdfebf302c3fb1de68867c5ba7d108/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/ComponentDescriptors.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/d33190217cee1149bf1eb73f43b78e2b/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/EventEmitters.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/607fbc6841e6853675265639618dc900/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/Props.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/d33190217cee1149bf1eb73f43b78e2b/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/ShadowNodes.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/607fbc6841e6853675265639618dc900/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/States.cpp.o rnscreens_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_rnscreens.dir/35cdfebf302c3fb1de68867c5ba7d108/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/rnscreens/rnscreensJSI-generated.cpp.o  C:/Users/ishan/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/7cf29c9c7897276728e6817bbf7880d8/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/libs/android.x86_64/libreactnative.so  C:/Users/ishan/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/7cf29c9c7897276728e6817bbf7880d8/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/jsi/libs/android.x86_64/libjsi.so  C:/Users/ishan/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/fd8d01c630f9457a6a91d04e2b86e69a/transformed/fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/libs/android.x86_64/libfbjni.so  -latomic -lm && cd ."

ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++_shared
I am using Android Ladybug, these are few of the additional information:\
buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 24
compileSdkVersion = 35
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"

my package.json::
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.4.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.7",
    "@mui/material": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.7.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "lottie-react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.35.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "zustand": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.0",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.0",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

working for few days but not able to understand why it is coming and how to solve it
I have invadiated my caches, restarted my android studio (saw somewhere that this helps), deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and done npm install but still nothing works
